# Using Bootstrap Modal In Place of Javascript Alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently building a website for a client and they have asked for a minimum order of 6 items to be bought. So if a customer only has 5 items and clicks checkout then they need to be warned that they must have a minimum of 6 items. I currently have a Javascript `alert` to warn them but this doesn't allow for customisation. I was looking to add a Bootstrap Modal but can't work out how this is done.

Here is the code that I have got so far:

```
<script>
    paypal.minicart.render();

    paypal.minicart.cart.on('checkout', function (evt) {
        var items = this.items(),
            len = items.length,
            total = 0,
            i;

        // Count the number of each item in the cart
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            total += items[i].get('quantity');
        }

        if (total < 6) {
            alert('The minimum order quantity is:\n\n3 Cases of Beer\n6 Bottles of Wine\n6 Bottles of Spirits.\n\nPlease add more to your shopping cart before checking out');
            evt.preventDefault();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/SeanWessell/4z16m6k4/

You need to add the markup for your modal.

HTML:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="cartMessage" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="cartMessageLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>

                </button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title" id="cartMessageLabel">Minimum Order Requirements Not Met</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">The minimum order quantity is:
                <ul>
                    <li>3 Cases of Beer</li>
                    <li>6 Bottles of Wine</li>
                    <li>6 Bottles of Spirits.</li>
                </ul>Please add more to your shopping cart before checking out</div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you need to trigger the modal when the condition is met.

```
$('#checkout').on('click', function (evt) {
    var total = 5
    if (total < 6) {
        $('#cartMessage').modal()
        evt.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alert function that dynamically injects a bootstrap modal and show a message. If the modal already is present in the DOM it will be reused.

```
var bsAlert = function(message) {
   if ($("#bs-alert").length == 0) {
      $('body').append('<div class="modal tabindex="-1" id="bs-alert">'+
        '<div class="modal-dialog">'+
            '<div class="modal-content">'+
              '<div class="modal-header">'+
                '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>'+
                '<h4 class="modal-title">Alert</h4>'+
              '</div>'+
              '<div class="modal-body">'+
                  message+
              '</div>'+
              '<div class="modal-footer">'+
                '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Ok</button>'+
              '</div>'+
            '</div>'+
          '</div>'+
        '</div>')
    } else {
        $("#bs-alert .modal-body").text(message);
    }    
    $("#bs-alert").modal();
}
```

show the alert with `bsAlert('hello world');`

you can replace the native `alert()` by

```
window.alert = bsAlert;
```

now `alert('test')` will show the bootstrap modal.

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/qg48fer1/**

Comment: Thanks very much for this